# access/login to user profile/folder in VM ubuntu 12.04 lts

Tags: 12.04, login, login-screen

When I click log in to login to my user profile, the screen turns black for a fews seconds you can see a few lines (trying to start and get kick out?) and then just returns to the log-in menu.
It logs me in as admin automatically. I don't have admin password either.
How can i access my user profile?
I am able to access the GRUB and select root but it ask for root password which i don't have. Here is the message:
`Give root password for maintenance (or type control-D to continue):`

**update**
I were able to reset the passwords after accessing GRUB thanks to : [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ThPAWo7e8LI) but it is still looping when i try to login.

Any insight?

Comment: What VM ? If it logs you in automatically, what is the problem ? If you nforgot your admin password see http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Comment: VMware. It does log me in automatically as admin not my profile

Comment: what do you mean but not your profile ? did you encrypt your home directory ? If so, that does not work with automatic login.

Comment: my home directory is not encrypted. I used to automatically login like the admin by clicking log in.  but since i forgot my password i login as admin and change the password so i can do some sudo cmd. but since then it is looping to the log in screen when i try to login to my profile.